# How to type the result of Papa.parse?

Tags: json, typescript, csv, papaparse

I'm using Papaparse with Typescript to parse a local file and it works well.

I'm doing it like this:

```js
parse(file, {
    header: true,
    dynamicTyping: true,
    complete: (results) =>
        console.log(results)
});
```

But I want to strongly type the result. I have an interface and the result of the parse will always return me an array of objects with the following properties:

```js
export interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    location: string;
}
```

How can we type the result ?

I found this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/hvtkta/enforcing_type_on_the_result_of_papaparse/) and I tried their solution but it doesn't work:

```
parse<Person[]>(file, {
    header: true,
    dynamicTyping: true,
    complete: (results: Person) =>
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results.age))
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `complete` callback doesn't return a `Person` object.

The function should look like:

```
import {ParseResult} from 'papaparse';

function(results: ParseResult<Person>){ ...}
```

See https://www.papaparse.com/docs#results and line 255 in [the typings file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/44512fd89986eb441fce9a95fa6f8d27d870afd3/types/papaparse/index.d.ts#L255)